# Killer who killed the protagonists wife, got executed then resurrected by a doctor and his woman assistant

Tags: identify-this-movie

US movie, late 1990's or early 2000's. Either a TV movie or a theatrical released movie.

Story Points:

- Protagonist is a cop and his African-american best friend is also a cop. During a party set at night, the wife goes inside the house to get something then the killer appears and kills her. Protagonist then chases the killer and catches him, and tries to kill him until his best friend talks him out of it.
- One scene has protagonist witness the killers execution via lethal injection, then has a nightmare about the killer then springing to life and crashing out of the chambers glass window.
- The killers body is taken by a middle aged man doctor and his woman assistant. They try to resurrect him but it appears to be a failure. Until much later, the killer returns to life and later kills the doctor.
- Protagonist learns of this and tries to take him down, but his best friend and other cops don't believe him. Protagonist also develops feeling for the doctors assistant.
- The killer then captures the assistant and I think wounds protagonist. Protagonist tries to rescue her, but when he finds them both, its revealed that assistant is in league with the killer. I don't know what happens next but best friend arrives to try and talk to protagonist but sees the killer. The killer then wounds best friend and he and assistant escape by car.
- Assistant gloats for a while until the killer reveals his plans to kill her too and handcuffs her but when protagonist arrives he tries to make a getaway. Ultimately, the killers car crashes and protagonist makes the car explode to ensure that the killer will stay dead for good.

It is not [Fallen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119099).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the exact plot of [Evil Never Dies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0355427/combined) (2003) with Thomas Gibson and Katherine Heigl.

> **If Detective Mark Ryan ever wanted to see someone executed, then serial killer William Charles Lee, who killed Ryan's wife, but even that doesn't satisfy him.** After five years of complaints against Ryan, the bitchy Community Relations official gets him banished as 'liaison' to the prestigious college's campus police. Luckily **his partner**, Chris Thomson, admires a real cop who isn't afraid to use his gun. When **professor Arkin** has all funds cut to continue ten years of nanotechnology research inserting DNA to **revive cells in a dead body, he and his foxy female assistant** go ahead 'privately' using a prison-supplied corps; Ryan interrupts them at the crucial phase, but not in time to stop it, and soon **suspects correctly the resurrected man is Lee**, whose murderous drive immediately strikes again, and more then once...

Also stars John Waters as Professor Arkin. Here's a preview clip: